# The best way to create a list of videos?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am going to create an app showing videos from firestore.

For now I am simply using variable   **List< Widget > videoList = []**

But what would be better choice to store it? i thought of hive database but it doesn't seem to be a good solution, since I want the list to be created/ updated with every start of the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing videos in a list is a really bad option as they would all sit in memory, almost certainly crashing your app. I would recommend one of two options.

1- Store them offline in your app's folder in the user's device directly. Then access the requested video.

2- Play the requested video on demand, do not store a bunch in a list.